# Can I shrink the transaction log file on a mirror database?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, mirroring

This is a followup question to [a previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/40599/6173) about why I couldn't shrink the log file on the principal database.

To make a long story short, I setup database mirroring but forgot to make sure the job that backed up the transaction log was running again, and the transaction log grew to almost 60GB.

Since mirroring was set up, this size increase was duplicated on the mirrored server, and eventually took up all the disk space and made the mirror database unusable.

Per [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35276/6173) about transaction log maintenance on a mirror database, you can't back up the log on the mirror, but when asked specifically in [comments](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35274/transaction-log-maintenance-on-mirror-database#comment62384_35276) about how to shrink an overgrown log file on a mirror database, a [comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35274/transaction-log-maintenance-on-mirror-database#comment62396_35276) was left that

> One way to do this would be to failover to the mirrored database and
>   do the shrink there. Thoroughly test this out in a non-production
>   environment to ensure it has the behavior you want/expect.

This seems to suggest that there might be other ways to shrink the log file on a mirror, and this method might not necessarily be safe to do on a production server.

Is there a way to safely shrink the transaction log file on a database mirror?

Comment: The only supported way is to shrink the file on the principal which will also shrink the file on the mirror.  If your mirror is no longer the same as the principal, you really do not want to attempt to failover to the mirror.  Break mirroring, and recreate it, as you said in your previous question.

Answer (score 7):

The `DBCC SHRINKFILE` command will be mirrored from the principal to the mirrored database.  Here's some proof.

Create a sample database on the principal:

```
create database MirroredDb;
go
```

Create the same database from a backup with `NORECOVERY`:

```
restore database MirroredDb
from disk = '\\backupdir\MirroredDb.bak'
with norecovery;
go
```

Setup your mirroring session however which way you choose.

On the **principal database** look at the database file sizes:

```
use MirroredDb;
go

select
    name,
    size
from sys.database_files;
```

My result set looks like this following:

```
name            size
MirroredDb      392
MirroredDb_log  104
```

On the **mirror database**, create a snapshot and look at the same information:

```
create database MirroredDbss
on
(
    name = 'MirroredDb',
    filename = 'c:\sqlserver\MirroedDb.ss'
)as snapshot of MirroredDb;

use MirroredDbss;
go

select
    name,
    size
from sys.database_files;
```

My result set looks like the following:

```
name            size
MirroredDb      392
MirroredDb_log  104
```

Now grow the transaction log file on the **principal database** (I brought it to 1 GB):

```
alter database MirroredDb
modify file
(
    name = MirroredDb_log,
    size = 1GB
);
go
```

Looking at the **principal database's** transaction log size, we now see the adjusted size:

```
use MirroredDb;
go

select
    name,
    size
from sys.database_files;
```

My result set looks like the following:

```
name            size
MirroredDb      392
MirroredDb_log  131072
```

Create another snapshot on the **mirrored database**, and look at the transaction log file size there:

```
create database MirroredDbss2
on
(
    name = 'MirroredDb',
    filename = 'c:\sqlserver\MirroedDb2.ss'
)as snapshot of MirroredDb;

use MirroredDbss2;
go

select
    name,
    size
from sys.database_files;
```

My result set looks like the following:

```
name            size
MirroredDb      392
MirroredDb_log  131072
```

Now do the `DBCC SHRINKFILE` on the **principal**:

```
use MirroredDb;
go

dbcc shrinkfile('MirroredDb_log', 0);
go

select
    name,
    size
from sys.database_files;
```

My result set is the following:

```
name            size
MirroredDb      392
MirroredDb_log  104
```

Create a third and final snapshot on the **mirrored database**, and look at the size:

```
create database MirroredDbss3
on
(
    name = 'MirroredDb',
    filename = 'c:\sqlserver\MirroedDb3.ss'
)as snapshot of MirroredDb;

use MirroredDbss3;
go

select
    name,
    size
from sys.database_files;
```

And I get the following result set:

```
name            size
MirroredDb      392
MirroredDb_log  104
```

So as you can see here, the `DBCC SHRINKFILE` command is in fact mirrored to the mirror database.

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize the size of the log file was copied from the principal server as well. But in the event that the mirror isn't functional due to the transaction log size, is the only solution to delete and recreate the mirror? There's no way to safely shrink the mirror log when the mirroring process isn't functional?

Comment: You can't connect to the mirrored database, therefore you can't run the `DBCC SHRINKFILE` on it.  As for if you can fix your mirror session without removing mirroring on that database, there's a little more investigation that would have to take place there.  It seems like it was suspended because of the file size.  Have you tried resuming the partner?

Comment: Yes, but it immediately went back to being suspended. I am presuming it is because too much time has passed since the mirroring stopped, so a lot of data still needs to be transferred before it gets to the "shrink log file" part. I was hoping there was some other way that I just wasn't aware of, such as something I could run from the mirror database to shrink the file, or some file system manipulation, but that doesn't appear to be the case. Your answer is still very helpful though, so thank you :)

Comment: Hope no longer.  Once the database gets suspended/disconnected and a log backup gets executed on the primary you are pretty much hosed on getting the mirror back in synch without a re-init.