# How to shrink over sized logs in Database Mirroring?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transaction-log, logs

I've searched the forums here at dba.se and other places on the Net and haven't found a specific answer.  I know this question looks similar to many, but the ones that I've found only address how to shrink a log file, which I already know how to perform.

I happen to be in one of those unique positions that a log shrink is necessary.

**My specific question is:**

When I perform a log shrink on the primary in a mirrored set, do I then failover and perform a log shrink on the "new" primary?

Or does this somehow replicate the changes to the secondary, making the manually failover unnecessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the shrink on the primary:

[Can I shrink the transaction log file on a mirror database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40609/can-i-shrink-the-transaction-log-file-on-a-mirror-database)

No need to fail over and shrink the secondary.

Comment: Thank you, Brent!  I was pretty sure that I performed a pretty thorough search on here and don't remember seeing that post.  Had I paid better attention, I wouldn't have posted this question.

Comment: @SeanPerkins I totally know that feeling. No worries!